# Is it a good idea to combine small numbers into one in JavaScript? (As a storage optimization solution)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, optimization, numbers, format

It is said that

> All numbers in javascript are  64bit floating point numbers.

I am wondering whether numbers are always use 64bit in memory?

I have a data structure like this (in C-style code)

```
{
  int x; // [0-9]
  int y; // [0-9]
  int d; // [0-3]
}
```

x and y will be absolutely within the range of [0-9] and the only possible value of d is 0, 1, 2, 3.

If I store them as 3 separated number, will the structure use 64bit * 3 = 192 bits = 24 Bytes?

If so, I would like to store it in one number, x * 100 + y * 10 + d, and this should only use 64 bits(8 Bytes). Is this better without considering CPU usage.

And I also considered about string solution.

```
x.toString() + y.toString() + d.toString();
```

because all x, y and d are less than 10, they should be only 1 character, 16 bits. 
So the structure become 16 bits * 3 = 48 bits = 6 Bytes. 
Is this the most storage optimized solution?

And how about the storage in mongoDB? If I store the data structure into mongoDB, is it the same situation?

---

I wrote a snippets to test the storage in mongo. 
The final structure includes 3 instances of structures above. And the total amount is 66816.

I stored them into 3 separated databases:

- layout-full (I lost an 's'): an array includes 3 {x: valueX, y: valueY, d: valueD}
- layouts-int: xydxydxyd (in decimal)  ex. 233250750 means {x:2,y:3,d:3},{x:2,y:5,d:0},{x:7,y:5,d:0}
- layouts-str: convert int above to 2-char string. String.fromCharCode(i >> 16) + String.fromCharCode(i & 0xFFFF)

And the result is...

```
> show dbs
layout-full     0.03125GB
layouts-int     0.03125GB
layouts-str     0.03125GB
```

But the details are...

collection in layout-full

```
"size" : 8017920,
"avgObjSize" : 120,
"storageSize" : 11182080,
```

collection in layouts-int

```
"size" : 2138112,
"avgObjSize" : 32,
"storageSize" : 5591040,
```

collection in layouts-str

```
"size" : 2405396,
"avgObjSize" : 36.000299329501914,
"storageSize" : 5591040,
```

From these results, I found the int storage is the most space saving method.

I also did this:

```
> db.tiny.save({})
> db.tiny.stats().avgObjSize
24
> db.tiny.remove()
> db.tiny.save({l:null})
> db.tiny.stats().avgObjSize
28
> db.tiny.remove()
> db.tiny.save({l:[{x:null,y:null,d:null},{x:null,y:null,d:null},{x:null,y:null,d:null}]})
> db.tiny.stats().avgObjSize
84
```

So the `_id` will use 24 bytes and the key part, `{l:`, will use 4 = 28 - 24 bytes.

And you can find that a integer uses 32 - 28 = 4 bytes, so integers less than 2^31 seems to be stored as 32-bit integer in mongo db.

Also the in string solution, a 2-char string uses 36 - 28 = 8 bytes, just equals the value I guessed.

And for the full-structure solution, from the last tiny db test, you can see that a structure without data uses 84 bytes, so data use 120 - 84 = 36 bytes = 9 * 4 bytes. And I have just 9 integer numbers in my final data structure (triple x,y,d). This also prove that integers are stored as 32-bit integer.

And why the empty structure uses 84 bytes?

Through some more experiments, I found that 1 array or empty json object uses 4 bytes, and a key uses  * 4.

So, the empty structure actually is

```
{                                               // 1 object +4 bytes       = 4
  '_id': ObjectId('0123456789abcdef012345678'), // 3-char key + 12-byte id = 24
  'l': [                                        // 1-char key + 1 array    = 8
    {'x': null, 'y': null, 'd': null},          // 1 object+ 3 keys        = 16
    {'x': null, 'y': null, 'd': null},          // 1 object+ 3 keys        = 16
    {'x': null, 'y': null, 'd': null}           // 1 object+ 3 keys        = 16
  ]
}
```

The result is 4 + 24 + 8 + 16 * 3 = 84 bytes.

I hope my experiments are useful for others.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Different interpreters will manage memory differently. Don't worry about how it might be done behind-the-scenes unless you're going to make a JS interpreter, or unless you've got some serious performance issues.

Comment: How many of these numbers will you be working with that you're agonizing over 24 bytes?

Comment: @deceze I am not sure the amount, but it should less then 64,000,000. Actually, I worry about the space it use because only 240MB is free on mongolab and I am not sure whether it is enough for me. Btw. I am really curious about the answer.

Comment: So even in the optimized case, 64,000,000 numbers would take about half a GB of memory, which is too much for any Javascript app (assuming execution in browser...). ;)

Comment: Well, if your app even comes close to that limit and you'd need to bend over backwards just to stay within your free trial limit, it may simply not be worth it. :)

Comment: @deceze I am working on a server-side application with express.js/node.js/mongodb. So that won't run in browser. And the amount is just a guess about the possible max. If use the string solution, the data might be controlled in 250MB if use the more accurate max, Math.pow(88, 3) * 64. (64000000 is Math.pow(100, 3) * 64) I won't load such a huge data in memory but millions of Bytes might be stored in db.

Comment: Try without the optimisations, then work on from there. Don't just guess.

Comment: @Len Thank you for your advice. I am also considering about computing all the possible values of the structure and store them into mongoDB in different solutions and then measure the size they used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will store the three numbers in a single-character string. The only way to do better is to use typed arrays, but I'm not sure that's an option here.

```
function showMeSomeMagic(x, y, d) {
  // we assume that:
  // - x, y are integers in the range [0 9] 
  // - d is an integer in the range [0 3]
  // if not add the appropriate checks/casting/coercing
  var n = (d << 8) + (y << 4) + x;
  // return a String made of a single Unicode code point in 
  // the range [0xE000 0xE399], i.e. inside the Unicode BMP PUA
  return String.fromCharCode( n + 0xE000 );
}

function showMeSomeInverseMagic(s) {
  // we assume that:
  // s is a String created by showMeSomeMagic
  var n = s.charCodeAt(0) - 0xE000;
  var x = n & 15;
  var y = (n >> 4) & 15;
  var d = (n >> 8) & 15;
  return { x:x, y:y, d:d };
}
```

edit: updated according to the OP comment

Comment: Thank you for your great solution! And I think 0xE<x><y><d> is also a solution. ex. x=3,y=8,d=2 the character becomes 0xE382. I think this might be more friendly for debugging because I can read the value of x, y, d directly if show numbers in hex. ps. Do you know whether the numbers always use 64bit in javascript?

Comment: @Programus in theory yes, they're always double floats. This doesn't apply, obviously, if we're talking about typed arrays. In practice the JS engine is free to do whatever it wants, as long as there's no discernible difference from the point of view of the application (e.g. the counter of a for loop can be often replaced by an integer; some engines do this when JITting)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also did some experiments and appended the results in my question. Actually I need to store three such structures as a set, so the integer solution is the best according to the experiments. But if store single structure, obviously your solution is the best one because it uses only 16-bit, half of an integer (32-bit).